# How to create Database in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

My Background is MySQL/PhpMyAdmin and there I can create easily new database by entering the name in Phpmyadmin, But I'm facing problem to creating database in Oracle SQL Developer... I already connected HR_ORACLE default database and test the connection. But I don't know how to create new database?

Answer (score 3):

You usually only have one database (=instance) in Oracle. A database in Oracle is something *completely* different than a database in MySQL. Actually MySQL calls databases "schemas" and that's what they are best mapped to in Oracle.

To create a new schema in Oracle, you create a new user. Those two things are more or less the same (there are some subtle differences, but as you are a beginner just assume that it's the same for now).

To create a new user, you need to connect as a privileged user (typically SYSTEM or SYS) and run the `CREATE USER` command.

I don't use SQL Developer but I think it has some DBA tools built-in that can probably help you with that. Just seach for "user management" or something similar. You do **not** want to create a new database if you have Oracle up and  running.

Further reading:

- [2 Day DBA - Administering User Accounts and Security](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-7FC1D8BE-4BB9-4642-A4CE-29CD2B8A5F23.htm#ADMQS007)
- [SQL Developer's User Guide - Create/Edit User](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/RPTUG/dialogs.htm#RPTUG41683)
- [Database Administrator's Guide - Managing Users and Securing the Database](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/secure.htm#ADMIN023)
- [Concepts Guide - Oracle Instance Architecture](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/part_inarch.htm#BABEDEIJ)

**Edit** (as you seem to be confused about the new user):

Each user can (by default) only access the tables that were created under that user (the ones that user owns). So if you create a second user `NEWBIE` and log in with that user, you won't be able to access the tables of the user (schema) `HR_ORACLE`. If you create a new table as `NEWBIE` that table is created in the schema `NEWBIE` and is owned by the user `NEWBIE`. The user `HR_ORACLE` can not access the tables owned by `NEWBIE` (unless given the necessary grants)

Comment: Good answer, but "one database (=instance)" ... *sucks-teeth*

Comment: @DavidAldridge: what's wrong with that? Having just one instance is pretty much what most people do. I rarely see multi-instance installations.

Comment: It's just not technically correct, is all, and it's something people get confused on without even realising it.

Comment: @DavidAldridge: hmm, are you saying that when you create a new database (through dbca) you do *not* create a new instance? (pluggable databases aside for now)

Comment: Well I suppose I am in a way. The instance is just the process and memory structures, so the instance is started separately anyway. It's not a big deal, I just think it's important not to conflate these separate and easily confused items.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name then how I can handle the different database? I  already have one default databause(HR_ORACLE) with SID orcl there are allot of tables... that could mess my new tables... can you help me? and by your answer,,, it looks like each user can access same database, because there is just one database.

Comment: @NewBie: again: you do not need another database. You just need another _user_.